# How can I get full facebook profile from ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api, owin

I am developing web app, where I need to get full information about facebook user. OAUTH2 login is done successfully. But after that when I call `graph.facebook.api` using provided access token I get only id, name and picture.

*The question is how can I get full user profile from facebook?*

In Startup.Auth.cs I have following code:

```
var facebookAuthOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
{
    AppId = "APP_ID_HERE",
    AppSecret = "APP_SECRET_HERE",
    Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
        {
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:facebook:accesstoken"
                                      , context.AccessToken
                                      , ClaimValueTypes.String
                                      , "Facebook"));
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:facebook:email"
                                      , context.AccessToken
                                      , ClaimValueTypes.Email
                                      , "Facebook"));
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:facebook:about"
                                      , context.AccessToken
                                      , ClaimValueTypes.String
                                      , "Facebook"));
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
};

app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookAuthOptions);
```

And in my controller I am calling facebook API like this:

```
var apiRequestUri = new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=email,name,about,picture&access_token=" + accessToken);

var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
var json = webClient.DownloadString(apiRequestUri);
var profile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookProfile>(json);
```

But what I get is only id, name and picture.
When I try similar query in graph api console, I can get all of the information required.
Any suggestions are welcome!
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by adding claims to the `facebookAuthOptions` for each of the field required. After user approves requested info, then I can successfully get response from Facebook API using token provided on authorization step.